# Unit testing for exceptions

Tags: haskell, hunit

Can I write a test case with `Test.HUnit` that checks whether a call throws an exception?

I only care whether it throws any error, regardless of what message it prints.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't specific to HUnit, but you can write a function to check whether an `IO` value throws:

```
λ> :set -XScopedTypeVariables
λ> import Control.Exception
λ> import Data.Functor
λ> import System.Environment

λ> throws io = catch (io $> False) $ \(e :: SomeException) -> pure True
throws :: IO a -> IO Bool

λ> sequence $ throws <$> [ getEnv "HOME", getEnv "whatever", error "a" ]
[False,True,True]
```

Comment: Yes, assuming you're using `error` to produce values of type `IO`. I've updated the answer to include this.

Comment: Thank you. I am probably missing something obvious but when I enter your code into repl I get an error for `throws io = ...`:

`Illegal type signature: 'SomeException'
      Type signatures are only allowed in patterns with ScopedTypeVariables`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I have some GHC extensions enabled by default in my `~/.ghc/ghci.conf`. Use `:set -XScopedTypeVariables` in the repl to enable that one.

Answer (score 2):

If by an "exception" you mean [`Exception`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#t:Exception) and it is being thrown in some `IO` code, then you can use [`catch` or `catches`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:catch). However, if you mean catching things like `error "Something bad happened"` *in pure code*, you are out of luck. If you are willing to do the handling in `IO`, you have more options:

```
ghci> import Control.Exception
ghci> catch (error "Eek") (\(ErrorCallWithLocation msg _) -> putStrLn msg) 
Eek
```

---

From the Haskell 2010 report [section 3](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-230003.1):

> Errors during expression evaluation, denoted by ⊥ (“bottom”), are indistinguishable by a Haskell program from non-termination.

Here is another way to think about it: notice that the moment we try to evaluate a value that is ⊥ (like `error "Help!"`) depends not on when this value was *created* but only when it was first *needed* (since Haskell is non-strict). A mechanism to catch this sort of error would then break referential transparency.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I needed it for the 'error' case.

Comment: @cberkay Added. As long as you are willing to catch inside the `IO` monad, it is possible.